# How to compare cell against a set of cells and get an associated value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to compare the date of a cell against a column that has multiple date and I see which one it matches and get the associated value. Here I put an image to explain myself better:

[image]

Column D is where I need to put the formula, which compares the dates in column A on sheet 1 with the dates in column A on sheet 2. If it matches, I need to multiply the values in column C on sheet 1 by the values in column B of sheet 2.

Here another image with an example to be clearer

[image]

I have a little idea that would be something like:

```
= YES (ERROR (MATCH (Sheet1! A4; Sheet2! A2: A32; 0)); Sheet1! C4 * X
```

In the x it should go B3, but I don't know how to get that cell in the search above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,sheet2!A:B,2)*C3
```

I have recreated your spreadsheets below.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]